# How to use remote_function and prevent javascript xss injection?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm maintaining a legacy code base and noticed the following code in one of our view erbs:

```
ui30_select_tag(filter[:param_name], options_for_select(filter[:options], filter[:selected]), {
  prompt: 'Select a filter...',
  onchange: remote_function(
    url: report_link_options[:url],
    with: report_link_options[:with],
    before: mask_expression
  )
})
```

If you send a url to the view with the proper query string params, you could be vulnerable to XSS attacks, so in order to test I sent a url with:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/report_benefit/update?plan_years=%2c236704494926'})%3balert(1)%2f%2f264lr9p7f
```

And voila, when I select the dropdown defined in the select tag above, my browser executes the alert that I tacked on to the plan_years parameter. The report_link_options[:with] is equal to `plan_years=,236704494926'});alert(1)//264lr9p7f`

Since the remote_function simply takes a `:with` parameter and creates the javascript, you can't really sanitize the string against xss attacks or any malicious js executing since it creates the ajax js with the parameters.

How can I prevent any malicious js being passed via the `:with` clause in remote_function?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand why a "plan_years" argument on the query string end up on that report_link_options hash. Can you explain why the function code depends on something from the URL? I would start with making it not depend on that but I don't understand where that's being used. And I also think the method is actually deprecated.

Comment: Hi @arieljuod, good question.  So the plan_years argument is used to render the page that the dropdown is on (passed from a previous screen) and the ajax call from the generated dropdown takes the same plan_years argument.

Comment: From the name `plan_years` it looks like it represents some kind of list of years, so, you should validate that `report_link_options[:with]` has the format you expect. Can you show an example of a valid url? you can add a validation with a regexp and if the `plan_years` parameter does not have that format rise an exception.

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod, that's a good suggestion and I can certainly take a look.  Is there no other way to validate the `with` clause (especially if there were multiple parameters)?  I think in this sample case with one parameter your suggestion would work and I'll probably end up doing that.  I'm still curious if there were a more generic solution to prevent any malicious js to get through...

Comment: The thing is that you can't prevent extra code since you need the rest of the code to work, that's why the best solution would be a regexp validation. Personally I wouldn't even set content of a function from the url, you are inviting people to do nasty things. I guess there are better and more secure techniques to do what you need to do (maybe using the flash hash or the session hash).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @arieljuod, I appreciate your input!